# Where is Haskell's if' function?

Tags: haskell

If you use `pointfree` on the code [`\b t f -> if b then t else f`](http://blunt.herokuapp.com/#input=%5Cb%20t%20f%20-%3E%20if%20b%20then%20t%20else%20f), the answer you get is `if'`.

Where is `if'` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=if%27), it is defined in the following three packages:

```
if' :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
```

1. [utility-ht](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht) - [Data.Bool.HT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht/docs/Data-Bool-HT.html)

   `if-then-else` as function.

   Example:

   ```
   if' (even n) "even" $
   if' (isPrime n) "prime" $
   "boring"
   ```
2. [plailude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plailude) - [Plailude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plailude/docs/Plailude.html)

   If `True` then the first value, else the second.
3. [CLASE](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/CLASE) - [Data.Cursor.CLASE.Util](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/CLASE/docs/Data-Cursor-CLASE-Util.html)

The two main search engines for Haskell that I know of are [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/).

Comment: Hayoo usually has better search results than Hoogle.

Comment: [FP Complete's Hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle) is the best of both worlds :-)

Comment: @luqui But their Haddocks don't have source links in type class instance declarations. :(

Answer (score 8):

It's worth mentioning that the `if'` function exists in `base` since version 4.7, but it's called `bool` (in style with `either` and `maybe`).

```
bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a
bool f _ False = f
bool _ t True  = t
```

is defined in [`Data.Bool`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/base/Data-Bool.html#v:bool).

Comment: Note that this takes the "else" branch before the "then" one. This is so that this is consistent with other catamorphism-builders like `maybe` and `either`, which take their arguments in the order of constructor declaration.